# what is the best background subtraction algorithm for detecting vehicles in road traffic jam?

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, background-subtraction, object-recognition

My problem is detecting vehicles. The camera is on traffic light stand facing downward with some degree. The problem is luminance, as the sun changes its position. So what background subtraction algorithm is robust for this situation? I only know frame differencing, mean filter and `MoG`.

Comment: Go with MoG and its robust. Withstands all climatically changes because It learns for new frame that appear. Making your background stable.

Comment: Thanks. I will. I was to put it on embedded system. Can you give me any adevice on it?

Comment: I can help you with the code but not sure with embedded system.

Answer (score 0):

For conditions in which the background changes in time, benefiting from a adaptive-based algorithms can put a smile on you mouth. 
Such algorithms try to learn the new background model when they see some changes in the pre-learned model, say sun-light variations. The one that I suggest you is the algorithm: `AdaptiveSelectiveBackgroundLearning`.
In some of my projects, I also benefit from `AdaptiveMedianBGS` method which is quite fast and robust to changes. If you're developing in C++ (OpenCV), you can find the BGS library so useful. There, you can find the implementation for lots of background subtraction methods. See the bgslibrary [here](https://github.com/andrewssobral/bgslibrary).